# Read text file into variables with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, variables

I have a text file located on the server that contains a list of events with their target time.  It looks something like the following:

```
2012/02/11-10:00:00 EventStart Red
2012/02/11-10:10:00 EventStop Green
...
```

What I need to do is somehow read the text file and based on the current time select the next upcoming event and assign each element for that event to a variable.  So for example if the time is currently 2012.02.11-10:08:00, javascript variables `time = '2012/02/11-10:10:00'; title = 'EventStop'; color = 'Green';` would be created.

I'm able to read the text file with:

```
jQuery.get('schedule.txt',function(data){
  alert(data);
});
```

Just don't know where to go from there, or if that's even the best way to start.  I do have control over the formatting of the text file, so modifying that is an option.

Comment: It looks like a something that should be done on the server, not on the client.

Comment: @gdoron I agree as well, however in this particular case it needs to be done on the client.

Comment: @gdoron. I agree too. **;-) lol**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You say you can modify the file's contents, so I suggest converting it to JSON (and separating the date/time).

```
[{"date": "2012/02/11", "time": "10:00:00", "title": "EventStart", "color": "Red"}, {"date": "2012/02/11", "time": "10:10:00", "title": "EventStop", "color": "Green"}]
```

Then you can use `getJSON` to get/parse it.

```
jQuery.getJSON('schedule.txt',function(data){
    // data is an array of objects
    $.each(data, function(){
       console.log(this.title); // log each title
    });
});
```

From here, you can read the times and figure out which one is the latest.  Something like this should work:

```
if(Date.now() <= Date.parse(this.date+' '+this.time))
```

So, putting it all together:

```
jQuery.getJSON('schedule.txt',function(data){
    var matchedSchedule = {};
    // data is an array of objects
    $.each(data, function(){
       if(Date.now() <= Date.parse(this.date+' '+this.time)){
          matchedSchedule = this;  // If time matches, set a variable to this object
          return false; // break the loop
       }
    });
    console.log(matchedSchedule.title);
    // to set a "global" variable, add it to `window`
    window.eventTitle = matchedSchedule.title;
});
```

Comment: Awesome.  Re-formatted the text file to JSON as suggested and am able to run the script above.  However I'm not getting the last part.  So how can I stop on the first match (for simplicity sake, current time is less than this.time) and assign a variable for each element (date, time, title, color)?

Comment: If you `return false;` in the function passed to `$.each`, it'll stop the loop.  If the time matches, then you can set the variables, and `return false;`.

Comment: That did the trick.  Had to use jQuery.ajax with async set to false instead of jQuery.getJSON else I could not get any of the set variables out (even using window.varname...).

Answer (score 5):

Without changing your text file

```
$.get('sometext.txt',function(data){
    var perLine=data.split('\n');
    var myVars=[];
    for(i=0;i<perLine.length;i++)
    {
    var line=perLine[i].split(' ');
    myVars[i]={
        'time':line[0],
        'event':line[1],
        'color':line[2]
        }
    }
    console.log(myVars);
    console.log(myVars[0].time);
    console.log(myVars[0].event);
    console.log(myVars[0].color);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've already done the hard part. Now just parse the data that is returned.

```
jQuery.get('schedule.txt',function(data){
  yourParseFunction(data);
});
```

Comment: So with this particular route, how would I create global variables from the function?  When I try to call variables created within that function they are not defined.

Comment: does @Rocket's answer help or do you still need an answer?

Comment: @Rocket's answer helps, but still curious on how to 'export' a variable from within the above function.

Comment: if you want to make it global then add it to the window namespace. You do that by either omitting the var keyword or directly with window.yay = 'yay'